# Detecting power loss in a microcontroller to save context

Tags: power, failure, voltage-detector

I am trying to detect sudden power loss in my micro controller to save its state before the MCU dies. I have been thinking to utilize one of my GPIO pin to detect the supply voltage and use a large capacitor (with a diode to stop reverse feeding into the GPIO) to get enough time to save the state. Below is my proposed solution.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8h0vJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Note -** My brownout voltage is 2.1V and blackout voltage is 1.67V. I have shown a load in the 5V section to represent some relays and LED's which are powered at 5V (not sure if this is relevant). Also the 10uF and 22uF are required for AMS1117 and 100nF is a decoupling capacitor.

My questions are

- Is this the best approach for such cases?
- Will it be better to use ADC pins instead of GPIO?
- Is IN4007 the correct diode to stop reverse feeding (3.3V, max load is 470mA)?
- Any other suggestions / improvements on the circuit?

Comment: Where did you find a 2 kilofarad capacitor?

Comment: @Finbarr Thanks for pointing that out. I have correct it.

Comment: not sure how big of a cap you have, but the only way i could get this to work a while back was with a cap on 12v, a buck to 3.3v, and a divider taking the 12v to 3v into the analog input. When the A0 dropped below 2.7 I wrote about 32 bytes to SPIFFS with about 90% sucess. If you want to fire off a wifi on-off, you need a bigger cap than my 3300. I've been meaning to retry with 5v 4f caps, but havn't yet.

Comment: Note that many MCUs (at least the Atmels I know) already provide a  brown-out detector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AMS1117 datasheet shows that it has a dropout voltage of 1.3 V max over the output voltage.
As a power fail indicator you need to detect when the 5 V supply drops to 4.3 V or less. After this point your AMS1117 output may start to drop. You have not specified the brownout voltage on your MCU, and you want to ensure you have time to save state before this voltage.

I'd suggest that you should set the detection mechanism to a higher voltage on the 5 V supply, since it's probably clearly out of spec at anything below 4.7 V.

Increasing the capacitance on the 3.3 v or 5 V supply can provide extra time, but putting a diode in series with the AMS1117 would be a bad idea since it's simply lowering the 3.3 V supplied to the MCU.

My suggestion would be to use a brownout detector such as the [TC54VX42](https://www.parallax.com/sites/default/files/downloads/603-00002-4.3V-Brownout-Datasheet.pdf) or 43 with an external divider from the 5 V supply to set your detection threshold. 
They show you in the datasheet exactly how to set it up:
[image]

If you want to add extra capacitance to give extra response time, add it to the 5 V supply or to that supplies unregulated input ...not the AMS1117 supply.

Comment: I have now added my brownout(2.1V) and blackout(1.67V) voltage to my question. I have some load at my 5V side and without a diode, wouldn't the capacitor feed them during the power failure? My assumption was that the diode will block this and capacitor charge will be available only to my MCU. This way, I thought I could make the capacitor smaller. I also find  it a difficult to source TC54, hence can you recommend something with common components ?

Comment: There are quite literally thousands to chose from under the PMIC-supervisors category on Digikey: https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-supervisors/691  ...you should have no problems finding a suitable solution.

Comment: How about the diode ? I hope detecting the voltage before the diode will be better as it isolates the capacitor ?